# Switch billing fields and shipping fields on WooCommerce Checkout Page using hooks and filters

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook

I've got a WooCommerce Checkout Page which has the Billing Section on the left (or top, on mobile) and the Shipping Fields on the right (or bottom).

I want to swap these around. I could do this by editing the following code on the form-checkout.php file but I don't want to do that because I don't like editing template files.

```
    <div class="col2-set" id="customer_details">
        <div class="col-1">
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2">
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to un-hook the relevant function 'checkout_form_billing' from the 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' hook and rehook it into the 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping'.

I've tried this

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing', array( self::$instance, 'checkout_form_billing' ) );
```

and

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing', 'checkout_form_billing' ) );
```

But neither seems to remove it. Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: When are you doing the remove_action()'s? Is it done after they are added?

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

http://hardcorewp.com/2012/enabling-action-and-filter-hook-removal-from-class-based-wordpress-plugins/

put in function.php your theme:

```
$instance = WC_Checkout::instance();
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing', array( $instance, 'checkout_form_billing' ) );
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. The provided link doesn't lead to a proper answer to the question.